# Is it possible to have different elements in a factor to have a same levels?

Tags: r, levels, r-factor

I googled many times and the result was not what I want:

A sample dataset is provided as below:

```
year = c(1991,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016,2021)

factor(a,levels = c(1991,1996,2001,2011,2016,2021))
```

The result was:

```
[1] 1991 1996 2001 <NA> 2011 2016 2021
Levels: 1991 1996 2001 2011 2016 2021
```

I want to set the level of `2006` to be the same as `2001`, therefore, my favorable outcome will be:

```
[1] 1991 1996 2001 2006 2011 2016 2021
Levels: 1991 1996 2001 2011 2016 2021
```

Is it possible to change the levels of `2006` to be the same as `2001` without changing the original content of the vector `year`?

Comment: Your favourable outcome doesn't seem possible - a factor can only contain elements that are one of the levels (or NA).

Comment: I am trying to use R to fit constrained glm, which is used in age-period-cohort model. That is why I want to set two elements in vector `year` to have the same level. Is it not possible to fit constrained glm in r? I googled many many times and still found nothing...

Comment: OK, so this is an XY problem. Forget you proposed approach.

Comment: either you can merge the factors in your data (maybe replace 2001 and 2006 with 200106), or the package `glmc` looks to have a more general way to set up constrained glm

Comment: I tried `glmc` before and it returned that the coefficients in glm contained `NA`, therefore constrained glm cannot be fitted... But I need this constraint to fit the glm, which is a deadloop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you dig into the source code of `factor`, I guess you will have the answer in your mind (I think it should be "No" to your question)

```
> factor
function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
    ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA)
{
    if (is.null(x))
        x <- character()
    nx <- names(x)
    if (missing(levels)) {
        y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
        ind <- order(y)
        levels <- unique(as.character(y)[ind])
    }
    force(ordered)
    if (!is.character(x))
        x <- as.character(x)
    levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]
    f <- match(x, levels)
    if (!is.null(nx))
        names(f) <- nx
    if (missing(labels)) {
        levels(f) <- as.character(levels)
    }
    else {
        nlab <- length(labels)
        if (nlab == length(levels)) {
            nlevs <- unique(xlevs <- as.character(labels))
            at <- attributes(f)
            at$levels <- nlevs
            f <- match(xlevs, nlevs)[f]
            attributes(f) <- at
        }
        else if (nlab == 1L)
            levels(f) <- paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))
        else stop(gettextf("invalid 'labels'; length %d should be 1 or %d",
            nlab, length(levels)), domain = NA)
    }
    class(f) <- c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
    f
}
<bytecode: 0x00000186f0fe3640>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

As we can see, `levels` is generated either by `unique(x, nmax = nmax)` if the `levels` argument is not provided, or, `levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]` with the given `levels`. That means, you are not possible to have a single `level` for two `x` values.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, not sure what your purpose is, but you can do perhaps something like this. The original values then will be the names.

```
year = c(1991,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016,2021,2006)

year2 <- factor(year,levels = c(1991,1996,2001,2006,2011,2016,2021), labels = c(1991,1996,2001,2001,2011,2016,2021))

names(year2) <- year

year2

1991 1996 2001 2006 2011 2016 2021 2006 
1991 1996 2001 2001 2011 2016 2021 2001 
Levels: 1991 1996 2001 2011 2016 2021

str(year2)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "1991","1996",..: 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 3
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "1991" "1996" "2001" "2006" ...
```